# Not able to locate an element using By.xpath

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I am facing problem with selenium webdriver to locate an element by xpath. I am not a web developer or tester. Something came up in my day to day task and need to connect to a website via script as part of automation.So can some one help me with this.

Given below xml, I would like autofill `Username` and `Password`.

```
<div class="fd-form-group">
    <div class="fd-form-item">
        <label class="fd-form-label">Username</label>
        <input autocomplete="username" class="fd-input" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>


<div class="fd-form-group">
    <div class="fd-form-item">
        <label class="fd-form-label">Password</label>
        <input autocomplete="current-password" class="fd-input" type="password">
        </div>
    </div>
```

As a first step I tried to locate these elements with below code

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/some/path/geckodriver")

  val driver = new FirefoxDriver()
  val myWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
  val myWebsite = "https://my/website"

  try {
    driver.get(myWebsite)

    // locate username
    myWait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@type='text']")))

  } finally driver.quit
```

I get this error :`Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for presence of element located by: By.xpath: //input[@type='text']`

I also tried with `@class`, but didnt help me.I am aware that this question is asked by many other users and solved with various method. But none of those helping me here as I dont know much about these things. So I really appreciate if some one helps

Answer (score 0):

You need to target input fields not label.

**UserName xpath** :

```
//label[text()='Username']/following-sibling::input
```

**Password xpath :**

```
//label[text()='Password']/following-sibling::input
```

and use it like below :

```
myWait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//label[text()='Username']/following-sibling::input"))).sendKeys("Your username")
```

I am not sure why you are using `driver.switchTo().defaultContent()` Is it in iframe ? or in a new window ?

Comment: Thanks @cruisepandey . I Tried your suggestions, but I get the same error. I have removed this `driver.switchTo().defaultContent() ` since it was not required

Comment: this is the error `Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Cannot locate an element using By.xpath: //label[text()='Username']/following-sibling::input`

Comment: try this xpath for username : `//input[@autocomplete='username' and @type='text']`

Comment: yeah.. I just tried. Same error :( . Problem is I dont get any detailed logs. So hard for me to debug it

Comment: I think it's in iframe, do one thing.. press f12 and go to elements and search `//iframe` and let me know if you see any yellow entries

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233171/discussion-between-rohan-nayak-and-cruisepandey).

Answer (score 0):

Accordingly to the details in your question I guess there is an `iframe` there so you have to switch into the `iframe` first and then try accessing those elements. Like this:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("frameId")));
myWait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@type='text']")))
```

and finally, when you finished with that `iframe` go back to the default content

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent()
```

Comment: I have removed this driver.switchTo().defaultContent()  since it was not required. I have updated my question

Comment: I see. I don't think that matters. You tried to wait for element existence.  If you see the element on the page but selenium is not able to locate it's existence I can only think about the iframe. Otherwise the element is just not that page or you are using wrong locator. But your locator is matching the HTML you provided...